# How to join two JavaScript Objects, without using JQUERY

Tags: javascript

I have two **json** objects obj1 and obj2, i want to merge them and crete a single json object.
The resultant json should have all the values from obj2 and the values from obj1 which is not present in obj2.

```
Question:

var obj1 = {
    "name":"manu",
    "age":23,
    "occupation":"SE"
}

var obj2 = {
    "name":"manu",
    "age":23,
    "country":"india"
}

Expected:

var result = {
    "name":"manu",
    "age":23,
    "occupation":"SE",
    "country":"india"
}
```

Comment: This question already been answered
        [Check This Post]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18498801/how-to-merge-two-json-objects-values-by-keys

Comment: That's [not JSON](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Answer (score 261):

There are couple of different solutions to achieve this:

**1 - Native javascript for-in loop**:

```
const result = {};
let key;

for (key in obj1) {
  if(obj1.hasOwnProperty(key)){
    result[key] = obj1[key];
  }
}

for (key in obj2) {
  if(obj2.hasOwnProperty(key)){
    result[key] = obj2[key];
  }
}
```

**2 - [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)**:

```
const result = {};

Object.keys(obj1)
  .forEach(key => result[key] = obj1[key]);

Object.keys(obj2)
  .forEach(key => result[key] = obj2[key]);
```

**3 - [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)**:
*(Browser compatibility: Chrome: 45, Firefox (Gecko): 34, Internet Explorer: No support, Edge: (Yes), Opera: 32, Safari: 9)*

```
const result = Object.assign({}, obj1, obj2);
```

**4 - [Spread Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)**:
Standardised from [ECMAScript 2015 (6th Edition, ECMA-262)](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/):

> Defined in several sections of the specification: [Array Initializer](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array-initializer), [Argument Lists](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-argument-lists)

Using this new syntax you could join/merge different objects into one object like this:

```
const result = {
  ...obj1,
  ...obj2,
};
```

**5 - [`jQuery.extend(target, obj1, obj2)`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/#jQuery-extend-target-object1-objectN)**:

Merge the contents of two or more objects together into the first object.

```
const target = {};

$.extend(target, obj1, obj2);
```

**6 - [`jQuery.extend(true, target, obj1, obj2)`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/#jQuery-extend-deep-target-object1-objectN)**:

Run a deep merge of the contents of two or more objects together into the target. Passing `false` for the first argument is not supported.

```
const target = {};

$.extend(true, target, obj1, obj2);
```

**7 - [Lodash `_.assignIn(object, [sources])`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#assignIn)**: also named as `_.extend`:

```
const result = {};

_.assignIn(result, obj1, obj2);
```

**8 - [Lodash `_.merge(object, [sources])`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#merge)**:

```
const result = _.merge(obj1, obj2);
```

**There are a couple of important differences between lodash's merge function and `Object.assign`:**

1- Although they both receive any number of objects but lodash's merge apply a deep merge of those objects but `Object.assign` only merges the first level. For instance:

```
_.isEqual(_.merge({
  x: {
    y: { key1: 'value1' },
  },
}, {
  x: {
    y: { key2: 'value2' },
  },
}), {
  x: {
    y: {
      key1: 'value1',
      key2: 'value2',
    },
  },
}); // true
```

BUT:

```
const result = Object.assign({
  x: {
    y: { key1: 'value1' },
  },
}, {
  x: {
    y: { key2: 'value2' },
  },
});
_.isEqual(result, {
  x: {
    y: {
      key1: 'value1',
      key2: 'value2',
    },
  },
}); // false
// AND
_.isEqual(result, {
  x: {
    y: {
      key2: 'value2',
    },
  },
}); // true
```

2- Another difference has to do with how `Object.assign` and `_.merge` interpret the `undefined` value:

```
_.isEqual(_.merge({x: 1}, {x: undefined}), { x: 1 }) // false
```

BUT:

```
_.isEqual(Object.assign({x: 1}, {x: undefined}), { x: undefined })// true
```

---

**Update 1:**

When using `for in` loop in JavaScript, we should be aware of our environment specially the possible prototype changes in the JavaScript types. For instance some of the older JavaScript libraries add new stuff to `Array.prototype` or even `Object.prototype`.
To safeguard your iterations over from the added stuff we could use `object.hasOwnProperty(key)` to mke sure the key is actually part of the object you are iterating over.

---

**Update 2:**

I updated my answer and added the solution number 4, which is a new JavaScript feature but not completely standardized yet. I am using it with [Babeljs](https://babeljs.io/) which is a compiler for writing next generation JavaScript.

---

**Update 3:**
I added the difference between `Object.assign` and `_.merge`.

Comment: For me, only this approach worked: `$.extend( true, object1, object2 );` (Merge object2 into object1, recursively). Ref.: http://researchhubs.com/post/computing/javascript/merge-content-of-objects.html

Comment: ^ Might want to note which approaches merge past the first level, in other words recursively.

Comment: Solution #4 didn't work for me in typescript: the merge indexes each operand using the variable name as a key, hence creating as many sub-arrays inside the overall result. Ridiculous. Solution #3, `assign`, did work.

Answer (score 15):

[**WORKING FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/pNQwY/111/)

Simplest Way with Jquery -

```
var finalObj = $.extend(obj1, obj2);
```

Without Jquery -

```
var finalobj={};
for(var _obj in obj1) finalobj[_obj ]=obj1[_obj];
for(var _obj in obj2) finalobj[_obj ]=obj2[_obj];
```

Comment: I guess the question says without using jquery

Comment: Useful Links- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10384845/merge-two-json-objects-in-to-one-object

Answer (score 9):

1)

```
var merged = {};
for(key in obj1)
    merged[key] = obj1[key];
for(key in obj2)
    merged[key] = obj2[key];
```

---

2)

```
var merged = {};
Object.keys(obj1).forEach(k => merged[k] = obj1[k]);
Object.keys(obj2).forEach(k => merged[k] = obj2[k]);
```

#### OR

```
Object.keys(obj1)
    .concat(Object.keys(obj2))
    .forEach(k => merged[k] = k in obj2 ? obj2[k] : obj1[k]);
```

---

3) Simplest way:

```
var merged = {};
Object.assign(merged, obj1, obj2);
```

Comment: Note that Object.assign() does return a value, so you could also write #3 as:
`var merged = Object.assign({}, obj1, obj2);`
Might actually be a tiny bit less perform-ant, but might be desire-able for readability depending on the code around it.

Answer (score 7):

Just another solution using [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#extend):

```
_.extend({}, obj1, obj2);
```

Answer (score 3):

This simple function recursively merges JSON objects, please notice that this function merges all JSON into first param (`target`), if you need new object modify this code.

```
var mergeJSON = function (target, add) {
    function isObject(obj) {
        if (typeof obj == "object") {
            for (var key in obj) {
                if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    return true; // search for first object prop
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    for (var key in add) {
        if (add.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            if (target[key] && isObject(target[key]) && isObject(add[key])) {
                this.mergeJSON(target[key], add[key]);
            } else {
                target[key] = add[key];
            }
        }
    }
    return target;
};
```

BTW instead of `isObject()` function may be used condition like this:

```
JSON.stringify(add[key])[0] == "{"
```

but this is not good solution, because it's will take a lot of resources if we have large JSON objects.

Comment: please add some explanation

Comment: This function `mergeJSON` work for me, many thanks

Answer (score 2):

I've used this function to merge objects in the past, I use it to add or update existing properties on `obj1` with values from `obj2`:

```
var _mergeRecursive = function(obj1, obj2) {

      //iterate over all the properties in the object which is being consumed
      for (var p in obj2) {
          // Property in destination object set; update its value.
          if ( obj2.hasOwnProperty(p) && typeof obj1[p] !== "undefined" ) {
            _mergeRecursive(obj1[p], obj2[p]);

          } else {
            //We don't have that level in the heirarchy so add it
            obj1[p] = obj2[p];

          }
     }
}
```

It will handle multiple levels of hierarchy as well as single level objects. I used it as part of a utility library for manipulating JSON objects. You can find it [here](https://github.com/stevenleadbeater/JSONT/blob/master/JSONT.js).

Comment: I assume you wrote that library then?

Comment: yes but it appears as though your stack overflow authoring skills put mine to shame. Thanks for all the fixes to the code sample @matsjoyce

Comment: Don't worry, I'm just a formatting freak (made mistakes my self, though). [This](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) is useful.

Comment: that's definitely getting a bookmark! thanks @matsjoyce