# How do I translate javascript object to a new object?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I need to import a few external json data into a variable or into a single json file to then display that data with D3.

This is the format of the data that I need to import from each json file:

```
    {
      "name": "name1",
      "version": "0.1.2",

      "references": [
        {
          "url1": "http://example1.com"
        },
        {
          "url2": "http://example2.com"
        }
      ]
    }
```

And this is the format of data that I need for the final json file/variable.

```
    {
      "nodes":[
        {
          "name": "name1",
          "version": "0.1.2",
          "references": [
            {
              "url1": "http://example1.com"
            },
            {
              "url2": "http://example2.com""
            }
          ]
        },

        {
          "name": "name2",
          "version": "1.6.0",
          "references": [
            {
              "url1": "http://example34.com"
            },
            {
              "url2": "http://example30.com""
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          ...
          ...
        }
      ],
      "links":[
      ]
    }
```

Basically I need to merge the data from the different json files inside the "nodes" array.

Any idea how could I do this?
Thanks

Comment: I don't think it's duplicating that topic, I think what he actually is asking for is how he can merge multiple JSON files into one...?

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate... the OP problem here is different.

Comment: Your right, not a dupe. Soooo... What have you tried? Anything? How x translates to y is not clear either

Comment: Not sure what you actually are looking for here OP, but can't you just push them to a single JS object? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21450060/how-to-join-two-json-object-in-javascript-without-using-jquery

Comment: Now I agree about the duplicate.

Comment: @liam Do you have to merge or just push?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nodes` is a simple array, so you can just push the 'file' objects into the `nodes` array.

```js
var file1 = {
    "name": "name1",
    "version": "0.1.2",
    "references": [
        {
            "url1": "http://example1.com"
        },
        {
            "url2": "http://example2.com"
        }
    ]
}

var file2 = {
    "name": "name1",
    "version": "0.1.2",
    "references": [
        {
            "url1": "http://example1.com"
        },
        {
            "url2": "http://example2.com"
        }
    ]
}

var files = [file1, file2];

var node = {
    "nodes": [],
    "links": []
}

files.forEach(function(file) {
    node.nodes.push(file);
})

console.log(node);
```

Comment: Thanks Marc! I think this should work for me! I will give it a try now.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply need to push all the data from the imported JSON into `nodes`, you can do this:

```
var imported =  {
    "name": "name1",
    "version": "0.1.2",
    "references": [
        {
            "url1": "http://example1.com"
        },
        {
            "url2": "http://example2.com"
        }
    ]
};

var finalJson = {
    nodes: []
};

finalJson.nodes.push(imported);
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vj1nqeu5/1/