# How to add values to an object property from another object having the same definition In JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, object, key-value

I have an object similar to the one below:

```
var obj1 = {
  fparams: {
    keys: ['a', 'b'],
    pairs: {
      'p': 'qwert'
    }
  },
  qparams: {
    'x': 'xyz'
  }
}
```

And another one as:

```
var obj2 = {
  fparams: {
    keys: ['c', 'd'],
    pairs: {
      'q': 'yuiop'
    }
  },
  qparams: {
    'z': 'zyx'
  }
}
```

What can I do to add the properties from `obj2` object to `obj1`?

As I am working in Angular, I tried to use `angular.merge(obj1,obj2)` but it does not merge the keys array, but overwrites it with the keys value from `obj2`, rest of the properties get merged though.

Here's what I want in the end:

```
var obj2 = {
  fparams: {
    keys: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
    pairs: {
      'p': 'qwert',
      'q': 'yuiop'
    }
  },
  qparams: {
    'x': 'xyz',
    'y': 'zyx'
  }
}
```

Also The angular Version I'm Using Is angular 1.5.8

Edit : Ended up using lodash , as it was much easier to work with and tons of functionalities which I was not previously aware of.

Comment: is this angular1.x or 2?

Comment: you might be interested in this thread
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21450060/how-to-join-two-json-object-in-javascript-without-using-jquery

Comment: merging the properties is fine ,its just that I'm not able to merge the arrays of the two objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess simply with pure JS and the help of the recursive function `mergeObjects` you can do as follows;

```js
function mergeObjects(o1,o2){
  return Object.keys(o1)
               .reduce(function(r,k){
                         o1[k] = Array.isArray(o1[k]) ? o1[k].concat(o2[k])
                                                      : typeof o1[k] === "object" ? mergeObjects(o1[k],o2[k])
                                                                                  : (r = Object.assign({},o1,o2),o1[k]);
                         return r;
                       }, o1);
}

var objs = [{
             fparams: {
                       keys : ['a', 'b'],
                       pairs: {
                               'p': 'qwert'
                              }
                      },
             qparams: {
                       'x': 'xyz'
                      }
            },
            {
             fparams: {
                       keys : ['c', 'd'],
                       pairs: {
                               'q': 'yuiop'
                              }
                       },
             qparams: {
                       'z': 'zyx'
                      }
            }],
  result = objs.reduce(mergeObjects);
console.log(JSON.stringify(result,null,2));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but why are additional object 'p' under 'pairs' and 'x' under 'qparams' being formed?

Comment: @Abhineet Sinha Yep.. totally my oversight. I have corrected the `: Object.assign({},o1,o2);` line to show `: (r = Object.assign({},o1,o2),o1[k]);` Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 3):

Did you consider using [Lodash](https://lodash.com)? It has a [merge](https://lodash.com/docs#merge) method that does exactly that.

Comment: Not using Lodash.

Answer (score 1):

With lodash you can use `mergeWith` and create desired result, so when value is array you need to concat values.

```js
var obj1 = {"fparams":{"keys":["a","b"],"pairs":{"p":"qwert"}},"qparams":{"x":"xyz"}}
var obj2 = {"fparams":{"keys":["c","d"],"pairs":{"q":"yuiop"}},"qparams":{"z":"zyx"}}

var result = _.mergeWith(obj1, obj2, function(a, b) {
  if(_.isArray(a)) return a.concat(b)
})

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Here is my attempt at deep merge, using recursion, not sure if it will work on all data structures.

```js
var obj1 = {"fparams":{"keys":["a","b"],"pairs":{"p":"qwert"}},"qparams":{"x":"xyz"}}
var obj2 = {"fparams":{"keys":["c","d"],"pairs":{"q":"yuiop"}},"qparams":{"z":"zyx"}}

function merge(o1, o2) {
  var result = {}
  for (var i in o1) {
    for (var j in o2) {
      if (i == j && typeof o1[i] == 'object' && typeof o2[j] == 'object') {
        if (Array.isArray(o1[i]) || Array.isArray(o2[j])) {
          result[i] = Array.isArray(o1[i]) ? o1[i].concat(o2[j]) : o2[j].concat(o1[i])
        } else {
          result[i] = Object.assign(result[i] || {}, merge(o1[i], o2[j]))
        }
      }
      if (typeof o1[i] != 'object' || typeof o2[j] != 'object') {
        result[i] = o1[i]
        result[j] = o2[j]
      }

    }
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(merge(obj1, obj2), 0, 4))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i'm not using lodash. I'm using angular1.x .

Comment: Is that the exact same structure of objects that you are working with or you need solution for objects of any structure and depth?

Comment: I'm able to merge the objects its just that I'm having difficulty in merging the array within the objects.

Comment: I'm using angularjs which has a function merge under module ng . angular.merge(obj1,obj2)

Comment: Ended up using lodash, wasn't aware about its functionality and usability. Thanks for the answer .

Answer (score 0):

try this function, I have tried to cover most of the scenarios though it might not be as good as other libraries available

```
var merge = function(obj1, obj2) {

  for (var key in obj2) {
    if (obj2.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
       if (obj1[key] == null) {
           obj1[key] = obj2[key];
       } else if (obj1[key] instanceof Array) {
           if (obj2[key] instanceof Array) {
               for (var i =0; i < obj2[key].length; i++){
                   if (obj1[key].indexOf(obj2[key]) === -1) {
                       obj1[key].push(obj2[key][i]);
                   }
               }
           }
       } else if (obj1[key] instanceof Object && obj2[key] instanceof Object && obj1[key].constructor == Object && obj2[key] == Object) {
           merge(obj1[key], obj2[key]);
       }
    }
  }
}
```

You can use it as below

```
merge(obj1, obj2);
```