# JSON objects merge in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two JSON objects:

```
result:{
       name:ABC
       }
```

and

```
result:{
       city:PQR
       }
```

I want to merge both and get output as following:

```
result:{
       name:ABC,
       city:PQR
       }
```

Comment: Looks like it has already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21450060/how-to-join-two-json-object-in-javascript-without-using-jquery

Comment: Did you even search on google or SO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
 var obj1 = { name:ABC }
 var obj2 = { city:PQR }

 const merged = Object.assign({}, obj1, obj2);
```