# is it posssible to push json into another json inside function

Tags: javascript, json

I have a problem to inserting new json into old json, have been tried to find it but I don't know the right keyword,

let say I have a json on `foo1.js`:

```
function jsonapi(){
  var ItemJSON = {
    "salutation":"foo1"
    ,"location":"foo2"
    ,"reference_code":"foo3"
  }
}
```

and on `foo2.js` :

```
jsonapi();
var json = {
  ,"isCustomer":"foo4"
  ,"email_to":"foo5"
  ,"phone":"foo6"
}
```

`Goal :`

```
{
  "salutation":"foo1"
  ,"location":"foo2"
  ,"reference_code":"foo3"
  ,"isCustomer":"foo4"
  ,"email_to":"foo5"
  ,"phone":"foo6"
}
```

there's a way to archieve my goal?

Comment: That's not JSON. Is it possible to "merge JavaScript objects"? Yes. Of course, having *access* to both objects at the same time is pretty much a prerequisite (ie. return the first object, pass in the second object, use a global variable, or some other combination).. Then it's just `f(obj1, obj2)` where `f` is the function that "merges" said objects; again, both `obj1` and `obj2` (neither of which are JSON in the shown code) are *available* at the same time.

Comment: no, you can't push a string into a string (easily)

Comment: @JaromandaX There are no JSON strings in the question.

Comment: Checkout `Object.assign`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: @user2864740 - I know that - but the title and question keep repeating `JSON`

Comment: So call it out: "Hey, that's not JSON! Those are two JavaScript objects. Merging JSON is hard because it's a string, but merging two JavaScript objects (that you have shown in the post) is easy because they aren't strings!" That is a big difference from saying "Strings [which you don't have because that is not JSON] are hard to merge."

Comment: @user2864740 may you give me an example code how to merge 2 JSObject?

Comment: @flix see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is declaration of variable inside the function.

Try as follows.

Declare variable as global and update it in function.

`foo1.js`

```
var itemJSON = {};

function jsonapi(){
   itemJSON = {
     "salutation":"foo1",
     "location":"foo2",
     "reference_code":"foo3"
   }
}
```

`foo2.js`

```
jsonapi();
var json = {
  "isCustomer":"foo4",
  "email_to":"foo5",
  "phone":"foo6"
};
```

Use `Object.assign` to combine two objects.

```
let output = Object.assign(itemJSON, json);
console.log(output);
```

**Another way:**

Return data from function in `foo1.js`.

`foo1.js`

```
function jsonapi(){
   return {
     "salutation":"foo1",
     "location":"foo2",
     "reference_code":"foo3"
   }
}
```

`foo2.js`

```
var itemJSON = jsonapi();
var json = {
  "isCustomer":"foo4",
  "email_to":"foo5",
  "phone":"foo6"
};

let output = Object.assign(itemJSON, json);
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a reasonably comprehensive answer here: [How to join two JavaScript Objects, without using JQUERY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21450060/how-to-join-two-javascript-objects-without-using-jquery)

However, stealing the first answer from the above link:

```
var result = {};
for(var key in obj1) result[key] = obj1[key];
for(var key in obj2) result[key] = obj2[key];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using Javascript .concat method.

More @ [Array.prototype.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

```js
var array1 = [
{
"name":"salutation",
"value":"foo1"
},
{
"name":"location",
"value":"foo2"
},
{
"name":"reference_code",
"value":"foo3"
}
];

var array2 = [
{
"name":"isCustomer",
"value":"foo4"
},
{
"name":"email_to",
"value":"foo5"
},
{
"name":"phone",
"value":"foo6"
}
];

console.log(array1.concat(array2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `jsonapi` as function ,so if you want to get that func value you need to return data !!! Take a look down at how `Object.assign` work ....

> The Object.assign() method is used to copy the values of all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object. It will return the target object.

```js
function jsonapi(){
   return {
    "salutation":"foo1","location":"foo2","reference_code":"foo3"
  };
}

var ItemJSON = jsonapi();

var json = {
  "isCustomer":"foo4"
  ,"email_to":"foo5"
  ,"phone":"foo6"
}

var result = Object.assign({},ItemJSON, json);
console.log(result);
```