# javascript How to create one JSON by combining two JSONs

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am facing an issue in small requirement. I want to create a JSON array in below format using JavaScript for loops.

```
var mainJson = {
        "people": [{
                "name": "Ravi",
                "role": "team member",
                "appointments": [{
                        "info": "room 1",
                        "type": "Type01"
                        "title": "Meet John Miller"
                    }, {
                        "info": "room 2",
                        "type": "Type02"
                        "title": "Meet Mitchell"
                    }]
            ]
        }
    };
```

To create above JSON, I have 2 jsons like below..

```
var subJson1 = [{
            "RowId": "00272727",
            "Rowlabel": "Ravi",
            "role": "team member"  
}]

var subJson2 = [{
      "info": "room 1",
      "RowId": "00272727",
      "type": "Type01",
      "title": "Meet John Miller"
      }, {
      "info": "room 2",
      "type": "Type02",
      "RowId": "00272727",
      "title": "Meet Mitchell"
      }]
```

Here in both **SubJson1** and **subJson2** "**RowID**" is the common parameter. Based on **RowId** we have to create **mainJson** .In the **mainJson** in **people** array objects will be more than 1. im just displaying only one item for understanding.

Im trying to achieve this with for loops. But im facing issues to resolve this. Can some one help me to create the **mainJson** using **subJson1** and **subJson2**

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How do you know which `subjson2` value will match with which `subjson1` value

Comment: JSON is a string format to represent javascript objects. What you have here are javascript object and array literals, not JSON.

Comment: My Mistake, I edited my question. Here based on RowId in subJsons i need to form main JSON. Can you please check now

Comment: @user3496976 please check my answer. It works as you expecting. If there's something misunderstood, please feel free to ask me.

Answer (score 0):

Will the sub JSON values always come through in the same format? If so you could skip the hassle of `for` loops and just pass the values through a function.

**EDIT:** Please see the edited answer below.

```
const subJson1 = [
    {
        "RowId": "00272727",
        "Rowlabel": "Ravi",
        "role": "team member"  
    }
]

const subJson2 = [
    {
    "info": "room 1",
    "RowId": "00272727",
    "type": "Type01",
    "title": "Meet John Miller"
    }, 
    {
    "info": "room 2",
    "type": "Type02",
    "RowId": "00272727",
    "title": "Meet Mitchell"
    }
]

const consolidateJSON = (subJson1, subJson2) => {
    return {
        people: [
            {
                name: subJson1[0].Rowlabel,
                role: subJson1[0].role,
                appointments: subJson2.map( item => {
                    const {info, type, title} = item;
                    return {
                        info,
                        type,
                        title
                    }
                } )
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: My Mistake, I edited my question. Here based on RowId in subJsons i need to form main JSON. Can you please check now

Comment: actually here subJson1 also an array it is not an object. Can you please help me in fixing that?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can map people with appointments by `RowId`, using ES6:

```js
const subJson1 = [{
  "RowId": "00272727",
  "Rowlabel": "Ravi",
  "role": "team member"  
}]

const subJson2 = [{
  "info": "room 1",
  "RowId": "00272727",
  "type": "Type01",
  "title": "Meet John Miller"
  }, {
  "info": "room 2",
  "type": "Type02",
  "RowId": "00272727",
  "title": "Meet Mitchell"
}]

/**
 * Get people, mapped with their appointments
 * 
 * @people {Object[]}
 * @appointments {Object[]}
*/
const getPeopleWithAppointments = (people, appointments) => ({
  people: people.map(person => ({
    ...person,
    appointments: appointments.filter(({ RowId }) => RowId === person.RowId)
  }))
})

console.log(getPeopleWithAppointments(subJson1, subJson2))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```js
var subJson1 = [{
  "RowId": "00272727",
  "Rowlabel": "Ravi",
  "role": "team member"  
}];

var subJson2 = [{
  "info": "room 1",
  "RowId": "00272727",
  "type": "Type01",
  "title": "Meet John Miller"
}, {
  "info": "room 2",
  "type": "Type02",
  "RowId": "00272727",
  "title": "Meet Mitchell"
}];

var mainJson = {"people" : []};

mainJson.people.push({"appointments" : subJson2.map(item => {
    delete item.RowId;
    return item;
  })
});

mainJson.people[0].name = subJson1[0].Rowlabel;
mainJson.people[0].role = subJson1[0].role;

console.log(mainJson);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are simply trying to merge two objects, there's a lot of utilities that do this, which I would defer to. SO Questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21450060/how-to-join-two-javascript-objects-without-using-jquery) also offer several ways to do it.

You, however, don't seem to be looking for that. In your case, you seem to want to create a new object with a new structure and insert the other two objects into it. For this, you would not use loops, but simply do the following:

```
var subJson1 = {
    "RowId": "00272727",
    "Rowlabel": "Ravi",
    "role": "team member"  
}

var subJson2 = [
    {
        "info": "room 1",
        "type": "Type01"
        "title": "Meet John Miller"
    },
    {
        "info": "room 2",
        "type": "Type02"
        "title": "Meet Mitchell"
    }
];

var mainJson = {
    "people": [{
        "name": subJson1.Rowlabel,
        "role": subJson1.role,
        "appointments": subJson2
    }]
};
```

Keep in mind; you don't need to put quotes around your keys in Javascript (.js files), only in JSON (.json files).

Comment: My Mistake, I edited my question. Here based on RowId in subJsons i need to form main JSON. Can you please check now