# How to update only Non Null Json fields of a Object in an Existing Json Object in Android

Tags: android, json, kotlin

Suppose, we have a `User` `JSON` response:

```
{
    "name": "Jack",
    "age": 28,
    "address": "Some address",
    "occupation": "Employee",
    "gender":"male"
}
```

With some network calls, we got another `JSON` response:

```
{ "age":"27", "address":"Some new address" }
```

Now, the requirement is to update the existing object with the updated fields. For e.g:

```
{
    "name": "Jack",
    "age":"27",
    "address":"Some new address",
    "occupation": "Employee",
    "gender":"male"
}
```

Notice that `age` and `address` was changed. This can be done by making `null` checks for small user object but doesn't look smart enough for some object like `Product` that will have more than 100 fields.

Looking for an efficient way to do it in `Java`/`Kotlin`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to join two JavaScript Objects, without using JQUERY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21450060/how-to-join-two-javascript-objects-without-using-jquery)

Comment: Which language? Java or Kotlin? Choose one...

Comment: What if use a dataBase, and update, only fields you need?

Comment: Kotlin will be preferred @Code-Apprentice

Comment: I am not looking for solution in JavaScript but in Java or kotlin

Comment: @codepeaker Start by breaking this into several smaller pieces. First you need to parse the JSON response. Then you need to determine how you represent the object in Kotlin. Then you need to update the individual fields in that representation.

Comment: @Alexander That will be one of the way, but Incorporating DB in an app won't be a good idea for the sake of solution

Comment: Traversing through individual fields won't be maintainable in the long run

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Helper in order to copy non null properties from object to another ? (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301697/helper-in-order-to-copy-non-null-properties-from-object-to-another-java)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a HashMap for it, let the value name be a key, and the value will be a value ))) :

```
HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>(); 


    hashMap.put("name", "Jack"); 
    hashMap.put( "age", "27");
```

Now, if you need to update values, just add it with the same key:

```
 hashMap.put( "age", "67");
```

Now you just need to iterate through your hashMap and get all values back, it could be like this:

```
 Iterator it = hashMap.entrySet().iterator();
 while (it.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
    System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " = " + pair.getValue());
    it.remove();
 }
```

And no dataBase, as you can see )))

Answer (score 1):

A `JSONObject` is essentially just a map of keys/values. Assuming you only care about one level deep, a trivial approach here would be to just map the key/values from the second object (where the values are not null) to the current object.

This could be defined as an extension function on `JSONObject`, such as:

```
fun JSONObject.mergeWith(other: JSONObject): JSONObject = apply {
    other.keys()
        .asSequence()
        .associateWith(other::get)
        .filterValues { it != null }
        .forEach { (key, value) -> this.put(key, value) }
}
```

For example:

```
val firstJson = JSONObject().apply {
    put("x", 1)
    put("y", "1")
}

val secondJson = JSONObject().apply {
    put("x", 2)
    put("y", null)
}

val mergedJson = firstJson.mergeWith(secondJson) // contains x = 2, y = "1"
```

Comment: Plus 1 Seems fine but I have to convert JSONObject to User object which I think is a overhead.

Comment: Alternatively I converted the class members to field array and merged both the object with null check.