# Merge two javascript objects if key is equal with either lodash, vanilla js, or d3

Tags: javascript, sorting, object, d3.js, lodash

I have 3 similar javascript objects.

```
var gdp = {
    "city": city,
    "gdp": [],  
};

var income = {
    "city": city,
    "income": [],  
};

var uRate = {
    "city": city,
    "uRate": [],  
};
```

Where I have many cities (n=28), and `[]` is my data array of integers with uniform length for each: `gdp, income, uRate`.

**GOAL:** Combine these into a single object for each city:

```
var finalData = {
    "city": city, 
    "gdp": [],
    "income": [],
    "uRate": [] 
}
```

I've tried variations of the following.

```
if ( ObjA.city == ObjB.city ) { Obj.city.metric = this.metric] };
```

Or, if **city matches**, add the metric (either gdp, income or uRate) to the `finalData` object.

```
cities.forEach(function ( city ) {

    var metrics = ['gdp', 'income', 'uRate'];

    metrics.forEach(function ( metric ) {

        if ( metric.city == city ) {  // edit: removed i

            var finalData = {
                "city": city, 
                "gdp": [],
                "income": [],
                "uRate": [] 
            };

        }    

    })

       return finalData;  // edit: moved this per suggestion

};
```

Here is a similar example using $.extend() with jQuery: [How to merge two object values by keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18498801/how-to-merge-two-json-objects-values-by-keys), but I am not using jQuery and would prefer either lodash, d3.js or vanilla js solution.

Thank You.

Comment: You need to move your `return` to after the loop. Also, what's `i`?

Comment: Ok, I have moved those around, thank you.  i was left over from previous failed attempt.

Comment: @DeBraid Have you looked at [_.extend](http://underscorejs.org/#extend)?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're doing. Since `gdp`, etc. have a single `city` property, how do you expect to come up with an array of objects? At most one `city` value will match `gdp.city`, etc.

Comment: Thanks Ted, I tried to grossly over-simplify what I am doing and it doesn't translate well!  I have found that _.merge takes 3 objects and will perform the desired operation!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using lodash  `_.merge` will satisfy the original question:

Given 3 objects:

```
var gdp = {
    "city": city,
    "gdp": [],  
};

var income = {
    "city": city,
    "income": [],  
};

var uRate = {
    "city": city,
    "uRate": [],  
};
```

Then bring in lodash and do:

```
var finalData = _.merge(gdp, income, uRate);
```

and the result is as desired:

```
{
    "city": city, 
    "gdp": [],
    "income": [],
    "uRate": [] 
}
```

Working solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/e99KQ/3/

Answer (score 5):

To anyone landing here from Google, it's now pretty easy to do this with vanilla JS using [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

This is a zero-dependency equivalent to the result in the accepted answer:

```
Object.assign({}, gdp, income, uRate);
```

Note that this won't work in IE, but *will* work in Edge. The [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Polyfill) isn't too heavy, though.

Working solution at https://jsfiddle.net/bLhk6x6a/1/