# PlayFramework: How to merge a sequence of JsValue instances to a single JSON document

Tags: json, scala, playframework

Given the following sequence of `JsValue` instances:

```
[
    { "name":"j3d" },
    { "location":"Germany" }
]
```

How do I merge them to a single JSON document like this?

```
{
    "name":"j3d",
    "location":"Germany"
}
```

Here below is my Scala code:

```
import play.api.libs.json._

val values = Seq(Json.obj("name":"j3d"), Json.obj("location":"Germany")
```

how do I merge all the JSON objects in `values`?

Comment: I think you on right track do this `Json.obj("name"->"j3d","location"->"Germany")`

Comment: [Merge the two objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18498801/how-to-merge-two-json-objects-values-by-keys)

Comment: Yes I know... but in my real case I have a `Seq[JsValue]` as an input.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a fold and `deepMerge`:

```
values.foldLeft(Json.obj())((obj, a) => obj.deepMerge(a.as[JsObject]))
```