# Merge multiple objects into single object with making array of same property values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have five json objects obj1 ,obj2,obj3,obj4 and obj5, i want to merge them and crete a single json object and obj have same columns. The resultant json should have all the values from all objects
Question:

```
var obj1 = {
    "DOP":"manu",
    "Resolution":23,
    "sensor":"SE"
}

var obj2 = {
    "DOP":"mansa",
    "Resolution":22,
    "sensor":"PS"
}
```

like that all five object data and results should update only rows not as columns and expected result should be

```
var result = {
    "Dop":["manu","mansa"],
    "Resolution":[23,25],
    "Sensor":["SE","PS"]
}
```

Comment: your result is not a valid json object

Comment: you can get result like this `var result = { "Dop":["manu","mansa"], "Resolution":[23,25], "Sensor":["SE","PS"] }`

Comment: Result is not valid json, let us know if that is the output you are after or do you need a valid merged json result?

Comment: @rachana, have you looked in my answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `for(x in obj)`

```
var result = {}
for (x in obj1) { result[x] = obj1[x] + ', ' + obj2[x] }
//Object {DOP: "manu, mansa", Resolution: "23, 22", sensor: "SE, PS"}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can merge object based on **passing unlimited objects as arguments** in `myCustomMerge()` function

```js
function myCustomMerge() {
    var return_obj = {};
    for (i in arguments) {
        obj = arguments[i];
        for (j in obj) {
            if (return_obj[j] == undefined) {
                return_obj[j] = [obj[j]];
            } else {
                return_obj[j].push(obj[j]);
            }
        }
    }
    return return_obj;
}


var obj1 = {
    "DOP": "manu",
    "Resolution": 23,
    "sensor": "SE"
}

var obj2 = {
    "DOP": "mansa",
    "Resolution": 22,
    "sensor": "PS",
    "special_obj2": "My Special Value"
}

var obj3 = {
    "DOP": "top",
    "Resolution": 36,
    "sensor": "ME",
    "special_obj2": "My Special Value 2"
}

var merged_obj = myCustomMerge(obj1, obj2, obj3);
console.log(merged_obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you want result is illegal.
All you can have array of your json.

```js
var result = [{ "DOP":"mansa", "Resolution":22, "sensor":"PS" },
              { "DOP":"manu", "Resolution":23, "sensor":"SE" }   
             ]
```

Comment: I didnt think this is solution for OP.

Comment: @HareshVidja It depends on how OP wants  output. You can't decide.

Comment: I have not decided output check question edit revision, http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39630651/revisions

Answer (score 0):

`var x ={ "student-marks":{'math':1,'physics':5} };
   var y ={ "student-marks":{'chemistry':3,'history':2} }; 
   $.extend(true, {}, x, y);`

I got the answer from here: [How to merge two object values by keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18498801/how-to-merge-two-object-values-by-keys)