# Merge two JSON objects containing arrays using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, merge, concatenation

I'm trying to merge two JSON objects which contains arrays:

```
var data1 = '{"resourceType": "test", "entry": [{"foo": 123, "test":"foo"},{"foo": 456, "test":"abc"}]}';
var data2 = '{"resourceType": "test", "entry": [{"foo": 789, "test":"bar"},{"foo": 102, "test":"def"}]}';

var json1 = JSON.parse(data1);
var json2 = JSON.parse(data2);

var obj = $.extend({},json1,json2);
console.log(obj);
```

but what I'm getting is overwritten by `data2` object when `.concat` will create an array with those two objects rather than wham I'm looking for is to get `entry` array of objects to be combined.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ashezpqx/)

Desired results should be like:

```
{"resourceType": "test", 
 "entry": [
    {"foo": 123, "test":"foo"},
    {"foo": 456, "test":"abc"},
    {"foo": 789, "test":"bar"},
    {"foo": 102, "test":"def"}
  ]
}
```

Any tips on that?

Comment: Have you tried merge instead of extend?

Comment: $.extend is shallow. the values are simply copied over.

Comment: What is the desired result?

Comment: @TA Yeah, I have tried that: `var obj = $.merge( $.merge( [], json1 ), json2 )`

Comment: @EECOLOR I have added desired result to the OP

Comment: Merge them manually. In this case you only have two objects, either with identical keys and one value that differs, just create a new object and merge the arrays.

Comment: @KevinB is this only the way to go in my case? If so post it as an answer. Thanks!

Comment: well no, there's *always* other ways to solve a problem.

Comment: @KevinB LOL _Yeah, I probably downvoted your post._ Now I know who did it :P

Comment: I mean... that only accounts for one of the two downvotes, ;)

Comment: Do you care about removing duplicates?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174664/discussion-between-jacktheknife-and-kevin-b).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the documentation of [jquery extend](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) you can see that you can pass `deep` as first argument:

```
var obj = $.extend(true, {},json1,json2);
```

With your test data, because the keys in the objects are named the same, the result will just have the second set of objects.

If you want some other result you need to update your question to clarify the desired effect.

---

**Update**

If you want the entries to be combined you can do something like this:

```
var entries = json1.entry.concat(json2.entry);
console.log(entries);
```

Comment: I agree. `deep` will make the difference.

Comment: @DiabolicWords Except... it won't. It doesn't combine values. It won't combine the two arrays into one, it'll simply throw one of them away.

Comment: @KevinB is correct - result is the same as w/o `deep`

Comment: And what about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18498801/how-to-merge-two-object-values-by-keys

Answer (score 0):

```
Merge two objects x and y deeply, returning a new merged object with the elements from both x and y.
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/deepmerge

http://jsfiddle.net/d38L6uhs

Comment: Interesting option